# Delete AKS nodepools by deleting it from de bicep template

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-bicep

I've created a template that creates an AKS cluster with two nodepools.
Now I tried to delete the second nodepool by removing it from the template.

```
az deployment group validate --resource-group <rsg-name> --template-file <template-filet.bicep> --parameters <parameterfile.json>
```

I tried it with both `--mode Incremental` and `--mode Complete`, but the nodepool isn't deleted. If I add new node pools to the template they are created like expected. So isn't it possible to delete node pools by editing the template?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, Node Pools are in a separated Resource Group. Meaning a complete deployment would only cleanup resources within the specified Resource Group - which is not the node pool Resource Group.

Comment: That is correct. What would be a good approach then? Any suggestions?

Comment: Use Azure CLI or PowerShell for example?